# I want to set an object to a property grid item with a button that will pop up a form. Not working as expected

Tags: c#, editor, type-conversion, propertygrid

So I have a property grid that I want to have an object bound to. When the application is running a button will show up and display a form which will allow that object to have its properties set and returned back to the property that called the form.

Here is what I have so far:

I cant get the property to show up in my property grid. Basically I want to use a form to fill in other items in the property grid.

I hope my question was clear enough...

```
   public class OptoSetupFormEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }


    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        IWindowsFormsEditorService svc = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;
        DataTemp opto = value as DataTemp;
        if (svc != null && opto != null)
        {
            using (OptoSigmaSetup form = new OptoSigmaSetup())
            {

                if (svc.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    opto.Direction = form.Direction;
                    opto.FunctionToCall = form.FunctionToCall;
                    opto.Duration = form.Duration;
                 //   OptoSigmaTest.Command = form.
                }
            }
        }
        return opto; // can also replace the wrapper object here
    }
}

  [Editor(typeof(OptoSetupFormEditor),typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public DataTemp Test1
    {
       set
       { 
           this.Duration  = value.Duration ;
           this.Direction = value.Direction; 
           this.FunctionUsed = value.FunctionToCall;
       }
    }


    [ReadOnly(true), Category("Setup")]
    public string FunctionUsed
    {
        get { return functionUsed; }
        set { functionUsed = value; }
    }


    [ReadOnly(true), Category("Setup")]
    public int Duration
    {
        get { return duration; }
        set { duration = value; }
    }

    [ReadOnly(true),Category("Setup")]
    public string Direction
    {
        get { return direction; }
        set { direction = value; }
    }

  public class DataTemp
{
    private int duration = 0;
    private string direction = "Positive";
    private string functionToCall = "Home";

    public string FunctionToCall
    {
        get { return functionToCall; }
        set { functionToCall = value; }
    }

    public int Duration
    {
        get { return duration; }
        set { duration = value; }
    }
    public string Direction
    {
        get { return direction; }
        set { direction = value; }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance. If it needs more clarification, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried augmenting the properties you wish to display with the `Browsable` attribute?

```
[Browsable(true)]
[ReadOnly(true), Category("Setup")]
public string FunctionUsed
{
    get { return functionUsed; }
    set { functionUsed = value; }
}
```

[MSDN: BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx)

EDIT:

Hm, according to MSDN, properties without this attribute, or those which have the attribute specified with a value of `true`, should display in `Property` windows; so this is a suggestion left wanting.